# Can't sync with a Windows Mobile device in Windows 7

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-7

I just upgraded my development PC from XP to Windows 7.  Along with all of the rest of the upgrade pain, I am currently facing a major roadblock.  To connect and sync with mobile devices, Windows 7 uses the Windows Mobile Device Center.  Somehow, my system has gotten into a state where the WMDC will not install.  Every time the setup program runs, a dialog box immediately displays that says "Setup Failed".  It then gives me the helpful advice to run the setup program again.  It does not, however, tell me why it failed.

Since I am currently in the middle of product development on a mobile project, mobile device connectivity is important.  It would be wonderful if Microsoft had given me a little more information to go on, but that is asking to much from our masters in Redmond.

Does anyone know of a solution to this problem, or at least of a log file that might help me track down where the break is.  I need more information in order to move forward.

Comment: Have you tried the obvious things like rebooting the PC?

Comment: I finally tries the un-obvious: Deleting the device AND the drivers in device manager.  The total purge allowed the system to refresh itself and correctly install the drivers on the second attempt.